# Emulating Google Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm really curious how Google (and now Facebook in the photo galleries) implemented shortcut keys such as <kbd>J</kbd>/<kbd>K</kbd> or <kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> arrows. I'm afraid I don't have many details because I can't figure out by inspecting the source which piece makes those buttons 'tic', so to speak. What I'm specifically looking for is a way to bind buttons to JavaScript functions - from there, it's obviously fairly easy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At its most basic, you just register a keydown event handler (on the document object if you want it to be global for the page) and then look at the event object to see which key was pressed.

Since different browsers handle events in different ways (I'm looking at Internet Explorer), I generally use an abstraction layer such as YUI or jQuery to normalise the differences.

YUI has an [example of implementing keyboard control](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/keylistener.html) as does [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/keypress) (although this example doesn't attach to the document object).

If you want to find out what keycodes relate to which keys, then I find it easiest to use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Run the following code in the Console:

```
document.onkeydown = function (ev) { console.log(ev); }
```

…then click on the page and press keys. The objects printed to the Console will tell you what keycode you just fired.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [js-hotkeys](http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/) ([jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) plugin).

I've used this plugin before in a production environment, so I tested it across all the a-grade browsers before I implemented it.. This was about three months ago.